# Django custom list_display in admin - problem in production server

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have a form where users submit sequences that are stored in the user_submission model. In Django admin, I have added a custom list display naming_algorithm (like below). It takes the obj. sequence and runs an external script and displays the output in HTML. It works locally well. When I try to use it on the production server it shows nginx 502 Bad Gateway. FYI: I use nginx and uWSGI for deployment. I am using Django 2.2 and Python3.7.

```
class UserSubmissionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = (
        'submittersname',
        'accession_url',
        'naming_algorithm',
    )

   def naming_algorithm(self, obj):
        if ">" in str(obj.sequence).split('\n')[0]:
            obj.sequence = '\n'.join(
                str(obj.sequence).split('\n')[1:])
        return format_html('<a href="/run_naming_algorithm/?fulltextarea={0}&submission_id={1}" target="_blank">Naming Algorithm</a>'.format(obj.sequence, obj.id))
```

I have a few questions

1. In the production server if I change DEBUG=True the above function works. If I change it to DEBUG=False nginx reports 502 Bad Gateway. Why this happens and how to approach the problem and fix it. Any pointers will help.
2. As you can see in the screenshot, I am passing the sequence through the URL. It seems to me there must be a better way to do it. I am unaware of it. Do you have any suggestions or alternative ways?

[image]

Comment: Does it work in production if you comment out the shared model along with DEBUG=False?

Comment: @HemantMalik yes it works in production if I keep DEBUG=False.

Answer (score 0):

Use mark_safe() around your html

```
return format_html(mark_safe('<a href="/run_naming_algorithm/?fulltextarea={0}&submission_id={1}" target="_blank">Naming Algorithm</a>'.format(obj.sequence, obj.id)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will test and update you on coming Monday.

Comment: I tried the suggestion it doesn't work. I have imported mark_safe `from django.utils.html import format_html, mark_safe`